# Equivalent of varchar(max) in ASE

Tags: t-sql, dynamic-sql, sap-ase-16

What is the equivalent of SQL Server's `varchar(max)` data type in ASE?

By ASE I mean what used to be known as Sybase ASE, which is now owned by SAP.

I'm attempting to execute a piece of dynamically constructed T-SQL that is longer than 8,000 chars.

If I declare a variable with `varchar(max)`, ASE chokes with:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'max'.
```

My next thought was to try the `text` datatype.  But alas:

```
You specified an incorrect datatype for the variable containing the 'execute immediate' command string.
```

A minimal, complete, and verifiable example:

```
DECLARE @cmd varchar(max) --change this to varchar(4000) and it works
SET @cmd = 'SELECT 1;'
EXEC (@cmd);
GO
```

Changing the variable declaration to `text` or whatever will suit your purposes.  I need to execute a dynamic command that is probably 50,000 characters long.

Alternately, I could use a cursor, but I am unfamiliar with how cursors work on ASE.

Note that in SQL Anywhere, you can define an equivalent to the varchar(max) datatype as `declare @cmd long varchar;`, however that won't work in ASE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASE's (var)char max is 16384. (assuming ASE 15.x/16.x)

If the query can be broken into chunks, with each chunk no larger than 16K, then you could try concatenating them inside the `execute()` call.

From the documentation for the [execute()](https://help.sap.com/viewer/e0d4539d39c34f52ae9ef822c2060077/16.0.3.7/en-US/ab2cd64abc2b101486cbba68f2c5a234.html) command:

> There are no restrictions to the number of characters supplied with
> the literal string.

And from **Example 6** (same link) we see a simple example:

```
execute ('select ' + @columname + ' from ' + @tablename + ' where id=3')
```